# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following is code for a TicTacToe program. I'm trying to write OO. I'm getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of undefined in the checkIfPositionIsTaken function when I click a box on my grid.

The following is the constructor for the TicTacToe Object:

```
var TicTacToe = function () {

this.player1Name = "Player 1";
this.player2Name = "Player 2";
var turn = "";
var grid = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
var hasWinner = 0;
var moveCount = 0;
}
```

The following is the checkIfPositionIsTaken function. I believe the error is on this.grid but it is defined when the object is created.

```
// Check If Position Is Taken
TicTacToe.prototype.checkIfPositionIsTaken = function(row, col){
   if(this.grid[row][col] !== 0){
      alert("This position is taken. Please try other position.");
      return true;
}
else{
    return false;
}
};
```

The following is where I create the TicTacToe object:

```
var theGame = new TicTacToe();
```

The following is my event for clicking a box on my grid:

```
// Column click event
$(".col").click(function(){

    var row = $(this).parent().index();
    var col = $(this).index();

    if(theGame.checkIfPositionIsTaken(row, col) == false &&       theGame.checkIfGameHasEnded() == false){

if(theGame.turn == theGame.player1Name){

    $(this).text(theGame.drawO(row, col));

    if(theGame.winnerCheck(1,theGame.player1Name) == false && theGame.checkIfGameIsADraw() == false){
           theGame.turn = theGame.player2Name;
           theGame.setBoardMsg(theGame.player2Name+"'s turn now!");
        }
        return; 
    }
else{

    $(this).text(theGame.drawX(row, col));

    if(theGame.winnerCheck(2,theGame.player2Name) == false && theGame.checkIfGameIsADraw() == false){
           theGame.turn = theGame.player1Name;
           theGame.setBoardMsg(theGame.player1Name+"'s turn now!");
        }
        return; 
        }
}
});
```

This is my first question so just let me know if you need more information. Thanks.

Comment: both row and col are setting to the correct value. The error is throwing when row and col are plugged into this.grid. `this.grid[row][col]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var grid = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
```

`grid` is a "local" variable to the `TicTacToe` method so `this.grid` is going to be undefined.

You are going to have the same problems with `turn`, `hasWinner`, `moveCount`.

Comment: So how would I make it work with TicTacToe as an object?

Comment: Look what you did with the player names.

Comment: Thanks. Still new to javascript learning something new everyday.